# How to align vertically items in th tag?

Tags: html, css, responsive

i have a table like this 
[table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VALiD.png)

how can i set all text position to center of the text box

here is my code

```
<table id="zero_config" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable"
                                       role="grid" aria-describedby="zero_config_info" style=" table-layout: fixed ;">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr >
                                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;padding-top: 0px;">Theo ngày</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;padding-top: 0px;">Tên đối tác</th>
                                        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center" >Giao dịch cũ - Đã khớp</th>
                                        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center" >Giao dịch mới đã khớp tự động</th>
                                        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center" >Giao dịch mới- Lệnh tự động, khớp nhân công</th>
                                        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center" >Giao dịch mới - Chưa khớp</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr >
                                        <th style="text-align: center">Số lượng GD</th>
                                        <th style="text-align: center">Số gạch nợ (đã có VAT) </th>
                                        <th style="text-align: center">Số lượng GD</th>
                                        <th style="text-align: center">Số gạch nợ (đã có VAT)</th>
                                        <th class="text-center" style="text-align: center;">>Số lượng GD</th>
                                        <th style="text-align: center">Số gạch nợ (đã có VAT)</th>
                                        <th style="text-align: center">Số lượng GD </th>
                                        <th style="text-align: center">Số gạch nợ (đã có VAT)</th>

                                    </tr>

                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
```

Comment: I would suggest read about `flex box` which probably will help you with that very easy.In here you can have very nice explanation how to use it https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: flex box make my table broken

Comment: I ran your code into a sandbox and the texts were both vertically and horizontally centered. My guess is that you have some css classes interfering. I also suggest you use css selectors instead of inline style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my understanding your question, you just simple add `vertical-align: middle` to your table. If not, please detail more your question

```css
.table thead th {
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table id="zero_config" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" role="grid" aria-describedby="zero_config_info" style=" table-layout: fixed ;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;padding-top: 0px;">Theo ngày</th>
      <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;padding-top: 0px;">Tên đối tác</th>
      <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center">Giao dịch cũ - Đã khớp</th>
      <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center">Giao dịch mới đã khớp tự động</th>
      <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center">Giao dịch mới- Lệnh tự động, khớp nhân công</th>
      <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center">Giao dịch mới - Chưa khớp</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center">Số lượng GD</th>
      <th style="text-align: center">Số gạch nợ (đã có VAT) </th>
      <th style="text-align: center">Số lượng GD</th>
      <th style="text-align: center">Số gạch nợ (đã có VAT)</th>
      <th class="text-center" style="text-align: center;">>Số lượng GD</th>
      <th style="text-align: center">Số gạch nợ (đã có VAT)</th>
      <th style="text-align: center">Số lượng GD </th>
      <th style="text-align: center">Số gạch nợ (đã có VAT)</th>

    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add

```css
<style type="text/css">
    table, thead, tr, th {
        display: flex-box;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    th {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }
</style>
```

to your html code which you provide and everything is centered horizontally, vertically. Just understand how to use `flex-box` properly and you should be able to achieve layout you want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems You are using boostrap. Try add to th element:

`class="align-middle"` and `text-center`

like:

```
   <th class="align-middle text-center" rowspan="2">Theo ngày</th>
```